# The mesh isn't moving together with or as fast as the bone

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I'm trying 2d animation and I am facing a problem now: when I'm in pose mode and I move the bones of the hand, the mesh of the hand moves, but when I move the bone too high, the mesh doesn't follow up and has like a gap.

[image: screenshot showing mesh not following bone properly]

Comment: Ussually it is because object is affected also by another bone, but in that case you would see object distortion too. Probably better to upload simplified blend file  via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com (place code into Q) to let us check.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=J6AxXSD0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/J6AxXSD0/)

Comment: Thanks for file, just convention is to place code via "Edit" into Q, not into comment section. Can you move it there? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Vertex Group** in *Armature Modifier*, be sure Weight Paint of the object is absolutely red.

[image]

Or leave *Vertex Group* field empty.

[image]

Be sure other bones (small one) doesn't have influence to the object. Select Armature + Object, switch to Weight Paint mode and click on other bones to see if object is completely blue.

In your case Delete Armature Modifier called "Armature".

Comment: It doesn't works.

Comment: yes I see it from your file now, so my first comment was correct - other bone affects the object. answer edited by last sentence, but moonboots answer is more specific to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the other bones have influence on your mesh as well:

[image]
[image]

So either substract all influence in *Weight Paint* mode or go in the *Vertex Groups* list, select the groups that are not supposed to influence this bone (*Bone* and *Bone.001*) and click on the *Remove* button (or in your case you can even delete them):

[image]

Maybe next time for this kind of object, instead of parenting *With Automatic Weight*, use *With Empty Groups* then assign manually, or directly parent to the bone if the bone is supposed to control the whole object.

Not sure about your rigging though, why several armatures for example? You may have your reasons...

Comment: Yes, plus, judging from your screenshot, they're doing a subdiv on some really low poly stuff, and if that's happening after the armature modifier, that's going to affect the apparent position of things as well.  I'd never recommend armature deforming something that low poly.....  Maybe actually write one of the levels of subdiv so you can weight it.